Graha shanti solutions
I went to an astrologer and got to know that almost every graha is in its bad positon.. and for that he gave me some remedies.. in that few are done by myself.. like regular Pooja and chanting mantras.. but the problem is my timings are not good and i can't sit with peace and chant bcoz of the time.. and this is everydayy problem.. i have no problem in chanting but I have problem in managing time in the morning like how hard I try I just couldn't make my mind calm without being hurry or stressed and due to this it feels like a burden whenever I try to pray to god. And i want to know is there any way that I can chant mantras and have the same effect in calming those planets? Or any particular day in a week for all planets.. like one single day for all planets? Just give me a way.. and i don't want to sound rude or as a negative person.. hope you will understand my situation and answer. Thankyou. ((Also Im a student and my father is not cooperating in performing Shanti Pooja or any other Pooja) so suggest me smtg which can be done by myself)

This question is not appropriate for this forum. Send me your dob & place along with the time and I will see if I can help you (no fee). satvikminds@gmail.com
